# Updated/increment the existing value when a new orderId is pushed in Javascript

Tags: javascript

here is the array with the objects, and when i push a new object with order 2, i would like to increment the noOfSubmit whenever a new orderId is pushed , is there a way to achieve the following using javascript?

Input array

```
[{"orderId":1,"noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"A"},
{"orderId":1,"noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"B"},
{"orderId":1,"noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"C"},
{"orderId":1,"noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"D"}]
```

`{"orderId":2,"noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"E"}` - Push this to the array above

Expected output:

```
[{"orderId":1,"noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"A"},
{"orderId":1,"noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"B"},
{"orderId":1,"noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"C"},
{"orderId":1,"noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"D"},
{"orderId":2,"noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"E"}]
```

`{"orderId":2,"noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"F"}`  - Push this next to the same array above

Expected output:

```
[{"orderId":1,"noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"A"},
{"orderId":1,"noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"B"},
{"orderId":1,"noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"C"},
{"orderId":1,"noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"D"},
{"orderId":2,"noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"E"},
{"orderId":2,"noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"F"}]
```

`{"orderId":3,"noOfSubmit":1, "orderNo":"G"}` -->  now push this object

Expected output:

```
[{"orderId":1,"noOfSubmit":3,"orderNo":"A"},
{"orderId":1,"noOfSubmit":3,"orderNo":"B"},
{"orderId":1,"noOfSubmit":3,"orderNo":"C"},
{"orderId":1,"noOfSubmit":3,"orderNo":"D"},
{"orderId":2,"noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"E"},
{"orderId":2,"noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"F"},
{"orderId":3,"noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"G"} ]
```

`{"orderId":3,"noOfSubmit":1, "orderNo":"H"}` -->  now push this object

Expected output:

```
[{"orderId":1,"noOfSubmit":3,"orderNo":"A"},
{"orderId":1,"noOfSubmit":3,"orderNo":"B"},
{"orderId":1,"noOfSubmit":3,"orderNo":"C"},
{"orderId":1,"noOfSubmit":3,"orderNo":"D"},
{"orderId":2,"noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"E"},
{"orderId":2,"noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"F"},
{"orderId":3,"noOfSubmit":1, "orderNo":"G"},
{"orderId":3,"noOfSubmit":1, "orderNo":"H"} ]
```

**Edit: When a new order Id is pushed it should increment noOfSubmit like you advised, but at the same time it should also verify all the array records if orderId matches the first character after split by hyphen, increment noOfSubmit only for the records that matches. eg:"orderId":R1-1 (after split by -, in this case R1).

when R2 records are pushed, it should not auto increment noOfSubmit of the array records where orderId starts with R1.

likewise when R3- OrderId records are pushed, it should not increment noOfSubmit for all the records where OrderId includes to R1 and R2 after applying split by hyphen.

Input array

```
[{"orderId":R1-1,"noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"A"},
{"orderId":R1-1,"noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"B"},
{"orderId":R1-1,"noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"C"},
{"orderId":R1-1,"noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"D"}]
```

`{"orderId":R1-2,"noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"E"}` - Push this to the array above

Expected output:

```
[{"orderId":R1-1,"noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"A"},
{"orderId":R1-1,"noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"B"},
{"orderId":R1-1,"noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"C"},
{"orderId":R1-1,"noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"D"},
{"orderId":R1-2,"noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"E"}]
```

`{"orderId":R1-2,"noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"F"}` - Push this to the array above

Expected output:

```
[{"orderId":R1-1,"noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"A"},
{"orderId":R1-1,"noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"B"},
{"orderId":R1-1,"noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"C"},
{"orderId":R1-1,"noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"D"},
{"orderId":R1-2,"noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"E"},
{"orderId":R1-2,"noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"F"},]
```

`{"orderId":R1,"noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"G"}` - Push this to the array above

Expected output:

```
[{"orderId":R1-1,"noOfSubmit":3,"orderNo":"A"},
{"orderId":R1-1,"noOfSubmit":3,"orderNo":"B"},
{"orderId":R1-1,"noOfSubmit":3,"orderNo":"C"},
{"orderId":R1-1,"noOfSubmit":3,"orderNo":"D"},
{"orderId":R1-2,"noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"E"},
{"orderId":R1-2,"noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"F"},
{"orderId":R1,"noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"G"}]
```

`{"orderId":R2,"noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"H"}` - Push this to the array above

```
[{"orderId":R1-1,"noOfSubmit":3,"orderNo":"A"},
{"orderId":R1-1,"noOfSubmit":3,"orderNo":"B"},
{"orderId":R1-1,"noOfSubmit":3,"orderNo":"C"},
{"orderId":R1-1,"noOfSubmit":3,"orderNo":"D"},
{"orderId":R1-2,"noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"E"},
{"orderId":R1-2,"noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"F"},
{"orderId":R1,"noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"G"}
{"orderId":R2,"noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"H"}]
```

`{"orderId":R2,"noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"I"}` - Push this to the array above

```
[{"orderId":R1-1,"noOfSubmit":3,"orderNo":"A"},
{"orderId":R1-1,"noOfSubmit":3,"orderNo":"B"},
{"orderId":R1-1,"noOfSubmit":3,"orderNo":"C"},
{"orderId":R1-1,"noOfSubmit":3,"orderNo":"D"},
{"orderId":R1-2,"noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"E"},
{"orderId":R1-2,"noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"F"},
{"orderId":R2,"noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"G"},
{"orderId":R2,"noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"I"}]
```

`{"orderId":R3,"noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"I"}` - Push this to the array above

```
[{"orderId":R1-1,"noOfSubmit":3,"orderNo":"A"},
{"orderId":R1-1,"noOfSubmit":3,"orderNo":"B"},
{"orderId":R1-1,"noOfSubmit":3,"orderNo":"C"},
{"orderId":R1-1,"noOfSubmit":3,"orderNo":"D"},
{"orderId":R1-2,"noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"E"},
{"orderId":R1-2,"noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"F"},
{"orderId":R2,"noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"G"},
{"orderId":R2,"noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"I"},
{"orderId":R3,"noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"I"}]
```

Comment: Just use `array.push()` to add the object to the array.

Comment: Hi @Barmer, I use array.push to push the object to the array, but i would like to increment noOfSubmit value everytime a new orderId is pushed.

Comment: Before you push, loop through the array, incrementing `noOfSubmit` when necessary. I'm not sure I see the exact logic of when it should be incremented, though.

Comment: noOfSubmit of the existing orders should be incremented when a new orderId is pushed to the array. not sure how i can achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Before pushing the new object, search the existing array to determine if the order ID is new. If it is, go through the array and increment all the `noOfSubmit`. Then push the new item.

```js
const orders = [{"orderId":1,"noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"A"},
{"orderId":1,"noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"B"},
{"orderId":1,"noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"C"},
{"orderId":1,"noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"D"}];

function add_order(order_array, order) {
  if (!order_array.some(o => o.orderId == order.orderId)) {
    order_array.forEach(o => o.noOfSubmit++);
  }
  order_array.push(order);
}

add_order(orders, {"orderId":2,"noOfSubmit":1, "orderNo":"E"});
add_order(orders, {"orderId":2,"noOfSubmit":1, "orderNo":"F"});
add_order(orders, {"orderId":3,"noOfSubmit":1, "orderNo":"G"});
add_order(orders, {"orderId":3,"noOfSubmit":1, "orderNo":"H"});

console.log(orders);
```

Comment: Thank you so much,Much appreciated! , can you please explain why we use some here? when we have both order 1 and 2, when we push order id 3, will some look for all the records of both order 1 and 2, or ignore a few records that may have order 2 on them?

Comment: We want to check if this is a new order ID. It's only new if there are no order with orderId=3, the other order 1 and 2 don't matter.

Comment: Hi @Barmar, I do have slightly an another use case, that i updated above (Edit). Can you please advise how to achieve it?

Comment: If you have a different problem that shoiuld be a new question.

Comment: ok, thank you, posted a new one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76442393/updated-increment-the-existing-value-of-the-selected-records-when-a-new-orderid