# Updated/increment the existing value of the selected records when a new orderId is pushed in Javascript

Tags: javascript

When a new order Id is pushed it should increment noOfSubmit , but at the same time it should also verify all the array records if orderId matches the first character after applying split by hyphen, increment noOfSubmit only for the records that matches. eg:"orderId":R1-1 (after split by -, in this case R1).

when R2 records are pushed, it should not auto increment noOfSubmit of the array records where orderId starts with R1.

likewise when R3- OrderId records are pushed, it should not increment noOfSubmit for all the records where OrderId includes to R1 and R2 after applying split by hyphen.

Input array

```
[{"orderId":"R1-1","noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"A"},
{"orderId":"R1-1","noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"B"},
{"orderId":"R1-1","noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"C"},
{"orderId":"R1-1","noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"D"}]
```

`{"orderId":"R1-2","noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"E"}` - Push this to the array above

Expected output:

```
[{"orderId":"R1-1","noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"A"},
{"orderId":"R1-1","noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"B"},
{"orderId":"R1-1","noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"C"},
{"orderId":"R1-1","noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"D"},
{"orderId":"R1-2","noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"E"}]
```

`{"orderId":"R1-2","noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"F"}` - Push this to the array above

Expected output:

```
[{"orderId":"R1-1","noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"A"},
{"orderId":"R1-1","noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"B"},
{"orderId":"R1-1","noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"C"},
{"orderId":"R1-1","noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"D"},
{"orderId":"R1-2","noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"E"},
{"orderId":"R1-2","noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"F"},]
```

`{"orderId":"R1","noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"G"}` - Push this to the array above

Expected output:

```
[{"orderId":"R1-1","noOfSubmit":3,"orderNo":"A"},
{"orderId":"R1-1","noOfSubmit":3,"orderNo":"B"},
{"orderId":"R1-1","noOfSubmit":3,"orderNo":"C"},
{"orderId":"R1-1","noOfSubmit":3,"orderNo":"D"},
{"orderId":"R1-2","noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"E"},
{"orderId":"R1-2","noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"F"},
{"orderId":"R1","noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"G"}]
```

`{"orderId":"R2","noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"H"}` - Push this to the array above

```
[{"orderId":"R1-1","noOfSubmit":3,"orderNo":"A"},
{"orderId":"R1-1","noOfSubmit":3,"orderNo":"B"},
{"orderId":"R1-1","noOfSubmit":3,"orderNo":"C"},
{"orderId":"R1-1","noOfSubmit":3,"orderNo":"D"},
{"orderId":"R1-2","noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"E"},
{"orderId":"R1-2","noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"F"},
{"orderId":"R1","noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"G"}
{"orderId":"R2","noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"H"}]
```

`{"orderId":"R2-1,"noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"I"}` - Push this to the array above

```
[{"orderId":"R1-1","noOfSubmit":3,"orderNo":"A"},
{"orderId":"R1-1","noOfSubmit":3,"orderNo":"B"},
{"orderId":"R1-1","noOfSubmit":3,"orderNo":"C"},
{"orderId":"R1-1","noOfSubmit":3,"orderNo":"D"},
{"orderId":"R1-2","noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"E"},
{"orderId":"R1-2","noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"F"},
{"orderId":"R1","noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"G"},
{"orderId":"R2","noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"H"},
{"orderId":"R2-1","noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"I"}]
```

`{"orderId":"R3,"noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"J"}` - Push this to the array above

```
[{"orderId":"R1-1","noOfSubmit":3,"orderNo":"A"},
{"orderId":"R1-1","noOfSubmit":3,"orderNo":"B"},
{"orderId":"R1-1","noOfSubmit":3,"orderNo":"C"},
{"orderId":"R1-1","noOfSubmit":3,"orderNo":"D"},
{"orderId":"R1-2","noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"E"},
{"orderId":"R1-2","noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"F"},
{"orderId":"R2","noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"G"},
{"orderId":"R2","noOfSubmit":2,"orderNo":"H"},
{"orderId":"R2-1","noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"I"}
{"orderId":"R3","noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"J"}]
```

tried out both these solution.

1. This solution seems working, Can you please confirm if it is the right solution to use?

```js
const orders = [{"orderId":"R1-1","noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"A"},
    {"orderId":"R1-1","noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"B"},
    {"orderId":"R1-1","noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"C"},
    {"orderId":"R1-1","noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"D"}];

function add_order(order_array, order) {
    if (!order_array.some(o => o.orderId == order.orderId) && order_array.some(o =>o.orderId.includes(order.orderId.split("-")[0]))) {
        order_array.filter(a1 => a1.orderId.includes(order.orderId.split("-")[0])).forEach(o => o.noOfSubmit++);
    }
    order_array.push(order);
}

add_order(orders, {"orderId":"R1-2","noOfSubmit":1, "orderNo":"E"});
add_order(orders, {"orderId":"R1-2","noOfSubmit":1, "orderNo":"F"});
add_order(orders, {"orderId":"R1","noOfSubmit":1, "orderNo":"G"});
add_order(orders, {"orderId":"R1","noOfSubmit":1, "orderNo":"H"});
add_order(orders, {"orderId":"R2","noOfSubmit":1, "orderNo":"H"});

console.log(orders);
```

2. 

```js
const orders = [{"orderId":"R1-1","noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"A"},
    {"orderId":"R1-1","noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"B"},
    {"orderId":"R1-1","noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"C"},
    {"orderId":"R1-1","noOfSubmit":1,"orderNo":"D"}];

function add_order(order_array, order) {

    if (order_array.filter(a1 => a1.orderId.includes(order.orderId.split("-")[0]))) {
        order_array.filter(a1 => a1.orderId.includes(order.orderId.split("-")[0])).forEach(o => o.noOfSubmit++);
    }
    order_array.push(order);
}

add_order(orders, {"orderId":"R1-2","noOfSubmit":1, "orderNo":"E"});
add_order(orders, {"orderId":"R1-2","noOfSubmit":1, "orderNo":"F"});
add_order(orders, {"orderId":"R1","noOfSubmit":1, "orderNo":"G"});
add_order(orders, {"orderId":"R1","noOfSubmit":1, "orderNo":"H"});
add_order(orders, {"orderId":"R2","noOfSubmit":1, "orderNo":"H"});

console.log(orders);

Output --. it auto increments everytime.
[
  { orderId: 'R1-1', noOfSubmit: 5, orderNo: 'A' },
  { orderId: 'R1-1', noOfSubmit: 5, orderNo: 'B' },
  { orderId: 'R1-1', noOfSubmit: 5, orderNo: 'C' },
  { orderId: 'R1-1', noOfSubmit: 5, orderNo: 'D' },
  { orderId: 'R1-2', noOfSubmit: 4, orderNo: 'E' },
  { orderId: 'R1-2', noOfSubmit: 3, orderNo: 'F' },
  { orderId: 'R1', noOfSubmit: 2, orderNo: 'G' },
  { orderId: 'R1', noOfSubmit: 1, orderNo: 'H' },
  { orderId: 'R2', noOfSubmit: 1, orderNo: 'H' }
]
```

Comment: Is `R1-1` supposed to be a string? It needs to be in quotes.

Comment: Where is your JS code?  You've explained your requirement, but you haven't explained what problem you encountered.  Please edit your question and provide the code segment that demonstrates your best attempt at resolving your requirements, and then explain at what point in that code you aren't getting the result you expect.

Comment: Please show what you've tried. You've seen the general approach to problems like this in your last question, you should be able to come up with something on your own now.

Comment: Updated the code that i have tried.